# Django TemplateView vs DetailView

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm working on an app that has multiple user profile models that OneToOne field to auth.User. For a specific type of profile's dashboard, say VendorSales, is it better practice to write a DetailView that takes the VendorSales ID in the url, or to just use a TemplateView with no url pk's and reference request.user.vendorsales in the template and self.request.user.vendorsales in the context data?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a primary key or slug in the URL when you use `DetailView` -- you can override `get_object` and access the object via `self.request.user`.

```
def get_object(self):
    return self.request.user.vendorsales
```

Whether you use `DetailView` or `TemplateView`, you may find [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) useful to limit access to the view.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your view to survice a reload you should put some kind of an id in the url.

In the case you want your model your app/api in a RESTfull way then you should think about not just putting in an url but also understand this view as a new ressource -> resulting in a new view with little to no connections to the users view (except linking urls).